# javascript: two ways to use concat function

Tags: javascript, arrays

below are two different ways to use `concat`. `nameage` and `nameage2` produce somewhat different results, which also seem to be described differently in different browsers.

```
var name = ["david","ibrahim","lagan"];
var age = [23, 34, 24];

var nameage = name.concat(age);
var nameage2 = [name].concat(age);
```

for example, in chrome:
`console.log(nameage);` produces "david,ibrahim,lagan23,34,24", whereas
`console.log(nameage2);` produces "["david,ibrahim,lagan", 23, 34, 24]"

Can someone explain what the difference is between these two approaches, and how it might impact use of `concat`? (Is one way more 'correct'?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second one, you're putting the "name" array inside an array, as its first element, and then concatenating the "age" array onto that.

So:

```
[name]
```

gives you

```
[ [ "david", "ibrahim", "lagan" ] ]
```

It's an array inside of an array. When you concatenate onto that, you get

```
[ [ "david", "ibrahim", "lagan" ], 23, 34, 24 ]
```

It's not correct to think of the two samples you posted as two "approaches" — they're two quite different things. Which is "correct"?  It depends on what result you want.

Comment: that makes sense; also it's consistent with the way Firefox displays the results. Do you have any idea why, in Chrome, the comma is omitted   between "lagan" and "23"? It seems like it should be 'all one array', thus including the comma.

Comment: Hmm .. Chrome isn't doing that for me when I `console.log()` those values. It shows the commas correctly.

Comment: for the first version (`nameage`)? interesting. it pulls the comma for me using both `console.log()` and `document.write()`.

Comment: @GregoryTippett wow Chrome is indeed doing some really weird stuff. I'm confused.

Comment: @GregoryTippett ah - I think it has to do with using the variable name "name" in the global context. Try using "theName" instead of just "name".  (The identifier "name" in the global context is special, as it has to do with the window's internal name? or something like that? I'm not sure.)

Comment: yes! that fixed it. the commas are there now in `document.write()`, and the console describes it as an array, rather than just listing it out with the commas.